# Can one recursively delete from a MySQL table without changing the schema to ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to recursively `delete` from a table in MySQL with a foreign key constraint without altering the table to `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Sometimes a `delete` does not succeed because a foreign key constraint fails and one does not want to change the database schema. Is there some way other than manually deleting all child items?

Comment: Two magic words for solving almost everything: Stored Procedure.

Comment: *Recursively*? No. Not without a sproc. But you *can* delete from more than one table in a single query.